# BGL BFS Getting all nodes within 2 depth of a given node

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I would like to know if Boost BGL BFS can be used to find all connected vertices from a given vertex up to a given depth level (e.g. 2). If so, how?

I am not very familiar with the visitor concepts so it would be helpful to know it can be done using the visitor.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you got? Can't you just use the distance map and filter for x<=2 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/graph/doc/distance_recorder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about [my answer yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46626276/85371), I realized there is a conceptual problem to your question.

#### *What distance is it anyway?*

When you do BFS, you do not get "actual" distances, you get "effective" distances, depending on the order in which vertices happen to be visited. That's useful information, but given that you are looking for nodes with a certain *maximum distance* it feels like you missed this part.

Indeed, DFS gives other results. If you don't care particularly about which search strategy is used, there's good news: `boost::depth_first_visit` takes an optional termination function¹

If you replace

```
breadth_first_search(g, s_source, 
            visitor(make_bfs_visitor(record_distances(distances.data(), on_tree_edge())))
            .color_map(colormap.data())
        );
```

with

> See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5dc852c7ae2af3e)</kbd>**

```
auto stop_when = [&](G::vertex_descriptor vd, ...) { return distances.at(vd)>=2.0; };

depth_first_visit(g, s_source,
        make_dfs_visitor(record_distances(distances.data(), on_tree_edge())),
        colormap.data(),
        stop_when
    );
```

you can make the algorithm do less work, so instead of the first image you get the second one:

[image]
  [image]

### Better Accuracy

Following along this path a bit further, you might realize you wanted *shortest* paths all along. Indeed, using `dijkstra_shortest_paths` would be more accurate (and happens to be equivalent to BFS if the edges have unit weight).

See **<kbd>[Dijkstra Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84f9e280cb1b5216)</kbd>** [image]

You'll notice that there is no way to prune the shortest-paths tree at some limit.

Depending on your actual scalability requirements and other constraints, perhaps the [`r_c_shortest_paths`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/graph/doc/r_c_shortest_paths.html) can help out here:

> The shortest path problem with resource constraints (SPPRC) seeks a shortest (cheapest, fastest) path in a directed graph with arbitrary arc lengths (travel times, costs) from an origin node to a destination node subject to one or more resource constraints.
>
> For example, one might seek a path of minimum length from s to t subject to the constraints that
>
> - the total travel time must not exceed some upper bound and/or
> - the total amount of some good that has to be picked up at the vertices along the path be less than or equal to some capacity limit and/or
> - if two vertices i and j are visited on a path, then i must be visited before j
> - etc.
>
> The problem is NP-hard in the strong sense [...]

---

¹ I guess it makes a bit of sense that it's more natural for DFS to have a termination function, where BFS cannot (because BFS will visit all peers recursively before descending to child nodes in the search tree; that could easily lead to entire chunks of trees being skipped because one branch was terminated). I suppose a similar mechanism could be added to the BF visitation algorithm though.

Comment: Thank you for the improvement on the original answer! I actually was trying with your original answer and it was working.

It is interesting that DFS actually provides a more optimised solution to my problem as I was thinking within BFS early termination.

Thank you for your input on the definition of distances. Indeed, it was something that I had left out when considering this problem. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So. I decided to try it: You use the `distance_recorder` by doing:

```
breadth_first_search(g, s_source, visitor(make_bfs_visitor(
        record_distances(distances.data(), on_tree_edge())
    ))
);
```

### Sample program

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b207c7626f64dedb)</kbd>**

```
using G = adjacency_list<>;
G::vertex_descriptor s_source = 8;

template<typename G> void save_graph(G const& g, std::string const& name, std::vector<double> const& distances);
void save_graph_filtered(double threshold, G const& g, std::string const& name, std::vector<double> const& distances);
G generate();

int main() {
    G g = generate();

    std::vector<double> distances(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<default_color_type> colormap(num_vertices(g));

    breadth_first_search(g, s_source, 
                visitor(make_bfs_visitor(record_distances(distances.data(), on_tree_edge())))
                .color_map(colormap.data())
    );

    for (auto vd : make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        if (colormap.at(vd) == default_color_type{}) 
            distances.at(vd) = -1;

    distances[s_source] = -2;
    save_graph(g, "dotgraph.txt", distances);

    // show only nodes at distance <= 2:
    save_graph_filtered(2.0, g, "dotgraph-filtered.txt", distances);
}
```

#### Generating Random Graph

This is really simple because BGL has it:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
// generate random graph
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <random>

size_t s_seed = 0xf5cab8bd; // std::random_device{}();
std::mt19937 s_rng {s_seed};

G generate() {
    G g;
    std::cout << "Seed used: " << std::hex << std::showbase << s_seed << "\n";
    boost::generate_random_graph(g, 20, 30, s_rng);
    return g;
}
```

> The hardcoded seed is what replicates the images in this post

#### Filtering for threshold distance

This can be quite simple as well:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
// filtering for threshold distance
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
void save_graph_filtered(double threshold, G const& g, std::string const& name, std::vector<double> const& distances) {
    filtered_graph<G, keep_all, std::function<bool(G::vertex_descriptor)>> 
        fg(g, {}, [&](G::vertex_descriptor vd) { return distances[vd]!=-1 && distances[vd]<=threshold; });

    save_graph(fg, name, distances);
}
```

> Note the check that `distance != -1` to rule out unreachable vertices.

#### Saving Pretty Graphviz Files

This is the most wildly unnecessary part, but it makes for pretty demo:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
// graph-viz demo output
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

template<typename G>
void save_graph(G const& g, std::string const& name, std::vector<double> const& distances) {
    using Vertex = typename G::vertex_descriptor;
    std::ofstream dotfile;
    dotfile.open(name);

    auto shape = [&distances](Vertex vd) {
        return (vd==s_source)?"circle":"Mrecord";
    };

    auto label = [&distances](Vertex vd) {
        std::ostringstream name;
        if (vd == s_source)                 name << "SOURCE";
        else                                name << vd;
        if (auto d = distances[vd]; d >= 0) name << "|distance: " << d;
        return name.str();
    };

    auto max = 1.25* *std::max_element(distances.begin(), distances.end());
    auto dist = [&distances,max](Vertex vd) {
        int r = 224, g = 160, b = 160;
        if (auto d = distances[vd]; d >= 0) {
            r = 255.0 * (1.0 - std::clamp(d, 0.0, max)/max);
            g = 255.0 * (1.0 - std::clamp(d, 0.0, max)/max);
            b = 255;
        }
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << std::setfill('0') << '#' << std::hex
            << std::setw(2) << r
            << std::setw(2) << g
            << std::setw(2) << b;
        return oss.str();
    };

    dynamic_properties dp;
    typed_identity_property_map<Vertex> v_;

    dp.property("node_id", get(vertex_index, g));
    dp.property("label", make_transform_value_property_map(label, v_));
    dp.property("shape", make_transform_value_property_map(shape, v_));
    //dp.property("shape", make_constant_property<Vertex>("Mrecord"s));
    dp.property("style", make_constant_property<Vertex>("filled"s));
    dp.property("fillcolor", make_transform_value_property_map(dist, v_));

    write_graphviz_dp(dotfile, g, dp);
}
```

### The ouput:

Unfiltered:

[image]

Filtered for the threshold value (2.0, in the sample):

[image]