# Using boost graph library to obtain induced subgraph reachable from vertex v with distance d

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm having problems in filtering the subgraphs using boost libraries, I want to obtain induced subgraph reachable from v with distance d. Here is the python code using networkx library:

```
def reachable_subgraph(G, v, d):
    E = nx.bfs_edges(G, v, depth_limit=d)
    N = set([n for e in E for n in e])
    return nx.induced_subgraph(G, N)
```

How can I do it using Boost library? Should I use bfs_visitors? I am not very familiar with the visitor concepts so it would be helpful to know it can be done using the visitor or any other Boost approaches.

Thanks!

Should I use bfs_visitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use the filtered_graph adaptor.

I like to push c++20 features to get as close to Pythonesque as I can:

```
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>

template <typename Graph, typename Nodes, typename V = typename Graph::vertex_descriptor>
auto induced_subgraph(Graph& g, Nodes nodes) {
    std::function f{[n = std::move(nodes)](V v) { return n.contains(v); }};
    return boost::filtered_graph(g, boost::keep_all{}, f);
}
```

Now, let's write your `reachable_subgraph` function:

```
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
template <typename Graph, typename V = typename Graph::vertex_descriptor>
auto reachable_subgraph(Graph& g, V source, unsigned depth) {
    std::vector<unsigned> dist(num_vertices(g));

    auto vis = make_bfs_visitor(record_distances(dist.data(), boost::on_tree_edge{}));
    breadth_first_search(g, source, visitor(vis));

    std::set<V> N;
    for (auto [b, e] = vertices(g); b != e; ++b)
        if (auto d = dist[*b]; d && d < depth)
            N.insert(*b);

    return induced_subgraph(g, std::move(N));
}
```

### DEMONSTRATION

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e35b835a26a4ece)**

```
int main() {
    boost::adjacency_list g;
    std::mt19937 prng(77); // manually selected for example
    generate_random_graph(g, 100, 150, prng);

    // print_graph(g);
    fmt::print("g has vertices [0..{}]\n", num_vertices(g) - 1);

    auto sub = reachable_subgraph(g, 5, 3);
    //fmt::print("nodes reachable < 3 from 5: {}\n", boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(sub)));

    print_graph(sub);
}
```

Prints

```
g has vertices [0..99]
8 --> 
13 --> 22 
14 --> 22 8 
22 --> 
27 --> 22 
31 --> 13 63 72 
35 --> 
50 --> 90 
63 --> 
72 --> 
90 --> 
97 --> 35 27
```

Comment: C++11 version http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/337da4b535e9ab80 and - gosh this was annoying to achieve: - a C++03 version (!!) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14539855a4336899

Comment: Wonderful! That's exactly what I needed. Appreciate it.

Comment: Just realized that the side-bar had an alternative old answer where I avoided the node-set that I copied without thinking from the python code. It could well save some time, depending on the graphs and usage patterns https://stackoverflow.com/a/46626276/85371 - Also,  welcome to [SO], please remember to vote (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks @sehe for your help. I have a follow up question, the make_bfs_visitor(record_distances(dist.data(), boost::on_tree_edge{}) explores the whole graph, I wonder would it be possible to terminate bfs earlier, for example if depth=1, in a huge graph, we only need to explore the outdegree edges for a vertex, and exploring the whole huge graph is not efficient. I wonder is there any way to terminate bfs search earlier? How can I avoid searching on the whole graph( boost::on_tree_edge{}).

Comment: I'd read the [same post I linked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46632577/85371) :) It points out that you can [use a `TerminatorFunc`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_visit.html#:~:text=IN%3A-,TerminatorFunc%20func) to cut off the discovery of vertices. Here's a simplified version of the code that also applies the optimization to not build the node-set anymore: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b97594b0cf6bca5d)**